# Regex Swift: How to find Two words OR Find Two words with a dash

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, regex

I have two regex patterns in Swift, both work for each case separately:

case twoWords = "(@\w+\s\w+)" = @User Name

case twoWordsWithDash = "@(\w+\s\w+\-\w+)" = @User Name-Hyphen

Question:

How can I combine these two regex patterns in their respective strings, so the regex will configure EITHER twoWords or twoWordsWithDash??

What I want:

case twoWordsORtwoWordsWithDash = "(@\w+\s\w+)|@(\w+\s\w+\-\w+)" = @User Name OR @User Name-Hyphen

But this fails, that OR operator | doesn't seem to work..

Comment: Can `@\w+\s\w+(\-\w+)?` be also another alternative to your needs?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to switch the order so that the user name with dash has priority over the one without:

```
(@\w+\s\w+\-\w+)|(@\w+\s\w+)
```

You can check it using [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sBFtiK/1)